# FLD m64fp Instruction

Tags: assembly

Eight consecutive bytes in memory contain the hex values 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 64, 9E, 40. An FLD m64fp instruction is executed. Its argument is the address of the first of these eight consecutive bytes. As a result of the FLD instruction, the value in ST(0) is now:

1)  1776.0

2)  1945.0

3)  2003.0

4)  1984.0

If someone could please explain to me how to go about this question, how exactly I can solve it, & what you think the answer might be as I am very very lost.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FLD loads a float into the stack. Because you're executing FLD m64fp it will load those 8 bytes (64-bit floating-point) in little-endian format into the stack. Therefore to work out ST(0) we can use the following code:

Java:

```
System.out.println(Double.longBitsToDouble(0x409E640000000000L));
```

C:

```
uint64_t u2 = 0x409E640000000000L;
printf("%lf\n", *((double*)&u2));
```

Which outputs 1945.0

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to run the code you wrote in linux (in C) but its telling me that U2 is undeclared. Here's how I wrote it out:union u2 {
    int64_t i1;
    float f1;
};




// do not change this function in any way
int main(void)
{

        u2.i1 = 0x409E640000000000L;
        printf("%lld\n", u2.i1);

}

Comment: You'll need to #include <cstdint> at the top, or else the compiler won't know what a uint64_t is

Comment: Check my updated code, I wrote the printf wrong the first time

Comment: *should be llf, not lld, my mistake :P

Comment: For some reason, I can't get this thing to work!!! :( sorry to keep bugging you but I keep getting the output as 45 no matter what i set u2 to be. Any suggestions?